# hidden popup event not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to trigger the callback function on the bootstrap close. But it is not working. My used code:

```
<div class="modal" id="overlayyy" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="custom-modal modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
          <iframe class="custom-iframe" id="myModalll" src="<?php echo $link; ?>"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Used:

```
$('#overlayyy').on('hidden.bs.modal', function ()
{
    alert('hide event fired!');
});
```

Comment: is the DOM ready before trying to bind things to them? (i.e inside `$(function(){ ... });` or placing the JS below the html)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check next points:

**1)** Have you included the library in the right way: [Bootstrap Starter Guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

**2)** Remove the `container` class inside the modal, just in case.

**3)** Check that your `custom-modal` class is not conflicting with Bootstrap Modal.

You can check the next working example using your code as the base.

```js
$('#overlayyy').on('hidden.bs.modal', function()
{
    alert('hide event fired!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#overlayyy">
  Open Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="overlayyy" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <iframe class="custom-iframe" id="myModalll" src=""></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```